# Cron job not working though command is working from the terminal on AWS EC2 instace

Tags: amazon-ec2, cron, ubuntu-18.04

I'm trying to run Laravel schedule through the cron job. I run this command from the terminal

```
php /home/USERNAME/htdocs/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Which sends an email and I get it without issues and have this inside `crontab -e`

```
* * * * * php /home/USERNAME/htdocs/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

But it doesn't work and I don't get the email. Should I write the full php path here? and how to find the correct one? I tried this in the terminal and in `crontab -e` but it didn't work. I got the path from `phpinfo()`

```
/opt/USERNAME/php /home/USERNAME/htdocs/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

How to make it work as a cron job correctly and what's wrong here?

Comment: Do you have any error lot while running the job?

Comment: don't know where to find logged errors!!

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/212357

Comment: cron.*: command not found

Answer (score 0):

I run

```
which php
```

and copied the full path and changed the cron command to be

```
* * * * * /opt/USERNAME/php/bin/php /home/USERNAME/htdocs/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

and it's working fine now.